# Same traces implies equivalent representation.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $D_{12}=\left<a,b:a^6=b^2=1, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\right>$
$, A= \begin{pmatrix}e^{i\pi/3}& 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\pi/3} \end{pmatrix}, $ $B=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$ $C=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}& \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \\ \frac{-\sqrt 3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix}1& 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

Prove that the following representations $\rho_k:D_{12} \to GL(2,\mathbb{C}) \ (k=1,2)$ given by:
$\rho_1 :a^rb^s\to A^rB^s , \  \rho_2:a^rb^s\to C^rD^s$ 
are equivalent.

Attempt: I manage to find $T$ that diagonalises $C$ and it turns out (coincidentally?) that $T^{-1}CT=A$ and $T^{-1}DT=B.$

I read that it suffices to check the representations have the same traces on all elements. Could someone explain to me why it is so? Thank you.

Comment: See here http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/KangD.pdf